# Setting Path variable using shell scripting - Using a shell variable

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I have variable difine as `SCRPT_PATH="/home/dasitha"` I need to add this path to .bashrc file using shell scirpt.

What I tired was something like this.

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$SCRPT_PATH")' >> /root/.bashrc
```

After opening my .bashrc file it looks like this

```
export PATH=$PATH:$SCRPT_PATH")
```

What I actually need is export PATH=$PATH:/home/dasitha. How should I do this by changing the shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the wrong quotes (in addition to a spurious looking parenthesis and quote mark). You're looking for something more like

`echo "export PATH=$PATH:$SCRPT_PATH" >> /root/.bashrc`

Here's a quick example that demonstrates quoting:

```
krismatth@earth ~$ echo $HOME
/Users/krismatth
krismatth@earth ~$ echo '$HOME'
$HOME
krismatth@earth ~$ echo "$HOME"
/Users/krismatth
```

Comment: Thanks @K. Matthews. But now my .bashrc file looks like this

`export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/dasitha`

What I expect is only something like this `export PATH=$PATH:/home/dasitha` Is it possible to make it ?

Comment: @Daz, I should've seen that, sorry. Something like this ought to do the trick:

Comment: (oops, I foolishly hit enter too soon) @Daz, I should've seen that, sorry. Something like this ought to do the trick: `echo "export PATH=\$PATH:$SCRPT_PATH" >> /root/.bashrc` (note the slash in front of $PATH).

Comment: Another possibilitiy would be `echo export PATH='$PATH':$SCRPT_PATH >>/root/.bashrc` . For me this would be a little bit more readable.